# How to center bottom fixed div?

Tags: css

I've tried to center my footer but the footer div will go straight to the left side. 
My page structure is:

```
<body>

    <div class="main_logo"> 
    </div>

    <div class="main_menu">
    </div>

    <div class="sub_menu">
    </div>

    <div class="main_content">
    </div>

    <div class="sys_breadcrumb">
    </div>

    <div class="sys_footer" >
    </div>

</body>
```

and the footer CSS is

```
height:50px;
width:1184px;
margin:-25px 368px 0 368px;
display:block;
```

and I added

```
position: fixed;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: Your "answer" was deleted because it did not answer the question. That's irrelevant to this, so I've removed that section.

Comment: The above css is applied to which element ?

Comment: You don't need any additional margin if you already position it right at the bottom of your page.

Comment: try "margin: 0 auto;" for the footer div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's fixed position, you (probably) don't need (or want) margins.  Delete the margin declaration and add:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -592px;
```

Note that 592 is half the width of your footer (1184).

Comment: if I add left:50% basically it will take the whole div to the right side and leave the very left of the div in the center of the page...

Comment: That's what the negative margin-left is for, to recenter it

Comment: resolved with: `position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 margin-left: -592px;
 left: 50%;` thanks

Comment: Can anyone explain to me, why you add ``left`` and "remove" it by adding a negative ``margin-left``?

Comment: Stefan- it's the only way to center the div because you don't know how wide the window will be, therefore you cannot determine how far from the left side of the screen to move the div.  This method moves the left side of the div to exactly the center of the window, then effectively nudges it back half it's width, centering it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your margin - and there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/96wMW/

```
.sys_footer {
    height:50px;
    width:1184px;
    display:block;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/vHNyb/5/

```
.sys_footer {
 background-color: red;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 width:1184px;
 margin:0;
 display:block;
}
```